# Why can't I use razor keyword in comments with user notification?

Tags: support, comments

I tried to include C# razor view engine keyword `@Html.Beginform` in comments with user name like **@Mr.Foo** .

But system shows this Error:

> Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always
>   be notified.

[image: razor keywords in comments]

I can understand that we can include only one user in comments  by above message. But why can't I include razor keywords in addition to that even though I used `Ctrl + k`  (ctrl+k is enough?)

Is their any trick to overcome this issue?

Comment: put it inside code marks like \`this\` so it will look like `this`

Comment: ctrl + k isn't enough ? How include code in comment? @JohnPalmer

Comment: Ctrl k doesn't work in comments.  Enclose in backticks like in my previous comment

Comment: yes it's working Thanks.BUt why ctrl + k isn't working ? @JohnPalmer

Comment: Because it's only a comment, not a full-featured post.

Comment: @ManirajSS: because CTRL-K only works in the post editor; comments are not posts and don't have an editor.

Comment: Thank you for providing an example of a case where you not only *should*, but *must* use code formatting in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword is *code*, so you should format it that way.

Stack Overflow thinks that you're trying to @reply multiple people because you're using the @ sign in plaintext. Enclose the keywords in backticks (`) to signify that they are code.

Formatted comment:

> @RajeshKannan How can I use Razor View Engine keywords in comments such as `@html.Beginform`?

Source:

```
@RajeshKannan How can I use Razor View Engine keywords in comments such as `@html.Beginform`?
```